# How to make indentifiable the RAID drive by CentOS7 on HP Proliant DL785 server?

Tags: hp-proliant, centos7

I have a HP Proliant DL785 server, and I want to install CentOS7 on it. But the installation is not commencing, as my RAID drives are not being identified by the installation setup.

Since I am a total newbie, can someone please guide me on how to do it or post some relevant reference links for help.

Comment: What is your raid controller, is it Smart Array P410 ?

Comment: Hi as per the spec it is : Smart Array P400i Controller

Answer (score 3):

If this machine has a Smart Array P410 raid controller, then it is no longer supported by Centos 7. You can install Centos 7 on it but you will have do some "trick".

The trick is to boot installation with `hpsa.hpsa_simple_mode=1 hpsa.hpsa_allow_any=1` options and after instalation, you will have to boot into rescue mode and change grub2 configuration addind same options as above to the `/etc/default/grub` file after that reconfigure grub with `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg`.

IMHO if you want to use this machine on production, then maybe it will be better if you use Centos 6.